# How to solve the legend error#2025 in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

thanks for seeing my post.
Go to the problem:
i have 2 Movieclip named "thebugboss" and "spiderboss"in the library, they all linkage to their Class. I drag it to stage and name it "bugboss" and "spiderbossit". I push them to the boss array too. When i kill the boss, it have some output message 2025 but my code still work.
But i worry because my code is not cleanly now, and i think it may be error everywhen. This is my code:

```
var currentboss:Number=0;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, defeatboss);
function defeatboss(e:Event):void
{
    for (var kb:int=0; kb<bossArray.length; kb++)
    {
        var bosshientai=bossArray[kb];
        if (bosshientai.hp<=0)
        {
            if (currentboss==0)
            {
                addReward(bosshientai.x ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                addReward(bosshientai.x-10 ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                addReward(bosshientai.x-20 ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                addReward(bosshientai.x-30 ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                removeChild(bosshientai);
                bossArray.splice(kb, 1);
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bugbossLoop);
                bugTimer.stop();
                bugTimer2.stop();
                bugTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, buggo);
                bugTimer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, bugstop);
                currentboss++;
            }
            if (currentboss==1)
            {
                addReward(bosshientai.x ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                addReward(bosshientai.x-10 ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                addReward(bosshientai.x-20 ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                addReward(bosshientai.x-30 ,bosshientai.y ,3);
                removeChild(bosshientai);
                bossArray.splice(kb, 1);
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, spiderLoop);
                spiTimer.stop();
                spiTimer2.stop();
                spiTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, spigo);
                spiTimer2.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, spistop);
                currentboss++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You just need to care about the "removeChild". it error like this:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at Holyshitman_fla::MainTimeline/defeatboss()
```

How to solve this problem plz, although my code still work. If that problem too difficult, just tell me is it affect to my game.

Thanks you so much. And sorry too, because my English is not good.

Comment: _`"they all linkage to their Class... I drag it to stage"`_ If you added linkage, then linkage name is now a **class** name. Don't use that same **class** name as also **instance** name. To fix... (option 1) : Don't drag anything, add to stage with code like `myBoss : thebugboss = new thebugboss();` assuming linkage name is **thebugboss** then removeChild by its name _"myBoss"_ ... (option 2) : Don't make linkage, now drag to stage and give an instance name instead then your code can removeChild.

Comment: Oh, thanks you. But my code is a noodle code, i cant use your opiton. This is a part of my code:

Comment: My understanding is `removeChild(bosshientai);` is causing problem. How did you add `bosshientai` to stage? I can see `var bosshientai=bossArray[kb];` but not  seeing the **addChild** part to add to stage (screen)

Comment: Ye, i drag "thebugboss" to the stage, then i name it "bugboss". I use this : bossArray.push(bugboss);. And the bosshientai is my var to target the "bugboss" in the bossArray.

Comment: addEnemy();
addDamage();

Comment: in the addEnemy() function i have a code: bossArray.push(bugboss);

Comment: in the addDamage() function i have a code: damageObjectArray.push(bugboss);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I drag **thebugboss** to the stage, then I name it `bugboss`. I use this : `bossArray.push(bugboss);`. And the **bosshientai** is like this"*

**Don't drag** the boss to stage. Add it by code. Your code like `bugboss.x` appears to work because it is talking to the stage object with instance name `bugboss`. 
**removeChild** expects a variable not a dragged item.

*`"The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller"`* The error happens because your shown code did not add it (you dragged), so now code cannot remove something that itself did not add.

Assuming linkage name is `thebugboss`:

1) Create new instance (*ie:* a new copy) of the `thebugboss` class:

```
public var bugboss : thebugboss = new thebugboss();
```

2) Add to stage and also add to array.

```
stage.AddChild(bugboss);
bossArray.push(bugboss);
```

3) Try your other code as usual (test `removeChild()` )

Comment: Where to put that code? The actions panel or put it in "thebugboss"  Class. My code is noodle code so it have a lot of inconvenient. Sorry!

Comment: Anyway, thanks you, you so enthusiasm when help me. I will back to my code, although it have output message#2025 but it still working. Your solution is so good and detailed. But my dump code is so stupid.  I have a lesson now. In the next project, I will try to forget the drag, the timeline and i think i need to learn more about OOP programing. Thanks you, PRO!!!

Comment: You must have a main class somewhere, I mean which `.as` file is attached to your FLA file as document class. It is the one that should add or removes `bugboss`. Control everything from main class (code for attacks, adding points, wins, etc). If you have a child class like `enemy` then just give it code for enemy stuff only (like movement or whatever),  if you need to run a function inside `enemy` class then call as `enemy.myFunction();`. If you need to check if `enemy` hits `player` then do that checking in main class then, still in main also run `enemy.getDestroyed();` as example. Good luck.

Comment: WOW! Thank you! You answer all my question in OOP. I just   prepare to ask all of that question. Thanks. By the way, how I contact you?